# How to create a Numpy 2d array with equal difference between rows?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

How can I create a (48,64) Numpy array like this:

```
i,      i,      i, .....,i
i+0.1,  i+0.1,..........,i+0.1
i+0.2,  i+0.2,..........,i+0.2
.
.
.
.
i+6.3,  i+6.3,..........,i+6.3
```

0.1 is the fixed difference between rows.

I have solved it perfectly with JoshAdel's answer,

But how about the fixed difference is between columns?i.e.

```
i,i+0.1,i+0.2.....i+6.3
i,i+0.1,i+0.2.....i+6.3
.
.
.
i,i+0.1,i+0.2.....i+6.3
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
i = 10.0
a = np.empty((64,48))
a.fill(i)
a += np.arange(0,6.4,0.1)[:,np.newaxis]

Out[12]: 
array([[ 10. ,  10. ,  10. , ...,  10. ,  10. ,  10. ],
       [ 10.1,  10.1,  10.1, ...,  10.1,  10.1,  10.1],
       [ 10.2,  10.2,  10.2, ...,  10.2,  10.2,  10.2],
       ..., 
       [ 16.1,  16.1,  16.1, ...,  16.1,  16.1,  16.1],
       [ 16.2,  16.2,  16.2, ...,  16.2,  16.2,  16.2],
       [ 16.3,  16.3,  16.3, ...,  16.3,  16.3,  16.3]])
```

A couple of notes:

- Numpy's shape convention is (nrow, ncolumn) so you need the shape to be (64,48) not (48,64) to the array that you have in your question.
- There are multiple ways to do this, but I chose to use numpy's [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) notation.
- You can write this more compactly, but I split it into separate steps for illustrative purposes.

Comment: another question..how can I do it column-wise?

Answer (score 0):

A different way to do this (just for fun) is using `tile` ([doc)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html)

```
c = 10 + np.cumsum(np.ones(64))*.1 - .1
a = np.tile(c,(48,1)).T
```